# On mobile select2 search hide when mobile keypad open

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

On Browser site work well.. but,when i open it on mobile problem i face like bellow image.
[image]

after scroll page down i see search box like this..
[image]

Any one help me solved this problem code is here.

```
<td colspan="2">
<select name="sel_specialities" id="sel_specialities"  data-placeholder="--<?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?>--" class="select" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    foreach ($specList as $spec) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $spec['SPEC_ID']; ?>" <?php echo $this->session->userdata('sel_specialities') == $spec['SPEC_ID'] ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> ><?php echo $spec['SPEC_NAME']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

### Script

$(function () {

```
$(".select").select2();
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your css

```
body .select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open {
    top: 305px!important;
    left: 22px!important;
}
.select2.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--below.select2-container--open {
    top: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome brother.